# The usage of infinitive as in "they insist that the results be overturned"

Tags: usage, infinitives

In:

> *they insist that the results be overturned*

is *should* or *have to* omitted? Is it something else?
Which chapter in grammar books explains this usage of infinitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to use the base form after verbs like *demand*, *insist*, *suggest*, *require*, particularly in formal situations and particularly in American English.

Historically this is a use of the *present subjunctive*, but I regard that as an unhelpful label since in modern English it is without exception identical to the base form of the verb.

Comment: Thank you. "Subjunctive" is what i was looking for.